# comparing the row value with rest of the rows

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 5x1 matrix , say `x=[6;8;4;2;9]` and what I want to do is compare row 1 with row 2,3,4,5 then row 2 with 3,4,5 , then row 3 with 4,5 and row 4 with row 5 and doing no comparison with last row.

Comment: What must be the output for the given input? Compare for equality?

Comment: @Divakar:i'll compare row 1 and rest of the rows . say row 1< row 2 i'll just ouput "value selected" .if condition isn't satisfied I simply say "value not selected". this is a small portion of a code I m writing and got stuck with this logic..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a little bit complicated solution, but it demonstrates useful matlab functions:

```
y=repmat(x,1,numel(x));
y==y'
```

So, first you replicate your column vector `x` to the square matrix. If `x=[6;8;4;2;9]`,

```
y= 6 6 6 6 6
   8 8 8 8 8
   4 4 4 4 4
   2 2 2 2 2
   9 9 9 9 9
```

Second line, `y==y'`, will compare term-by-term matrix `y` with transposed matrix `y'`. As a result, you will have a squre matrix `a_ij`, where `a_ij=1` if `x(i)=x(j)` and `0` otherwise.

The advantage is that you have to write 2 short commands.

**Edit**: after your comments, code should be:

```
y=repmat(x,1,numel(x));
a=y==y';
```

So matrix a is such that:`a_ij=1` if `x(i)<x(j)` and `0` otherwise. In order to do what you want, you can use for loops over the upper triangle (without diagonal values which are always zero) of this matrix and print  the results.

```
y=repmat(x,1,numel(x));
a=y==y';
for i=1:numel(x-1)
    for j=i+1:numel(x)
        if a(i,j)
            fprintf('value selected\n')
        else
            fprintf('value not selected\n')
        end
    end
end
```

Actually, if you decide to use for loops, it would be easier to do everything inside the for loop, without matrix calculation:

```
for i=1:numel(x-1)
    for j=i+1:numel(x)
        if x(i)<x(j)
            fprintf('value selected\n')
        else
            fprintf('value not selected\n')
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I think there is some miscommunication...when I run code I get 5x5 matrix , but I just want to compare rows in the order I mention and display whether value is selected or not..if let's say i compare row 2 with row 5, if row 2<row 5 display value selected..

Comment: i understood the code..but what is the point of numel(x-1)..its still gonna go till numel(x)..what is the significance of numel(x-1) ?

Comment: sorry, it should be `numel(x)-1`.